Does the deterministic sequence dominated by a random sequence converges to zero in deterministic sense if the random sequence converges a.s.
I am new to the concepts of different types of convergence of random sequences. Suppose $\{a_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a deterministic sequence. Let $\{X_k(\omega)\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a random sequence. I also have,
$0\leq a_k\leq X_k(\omega)$, $\forall k\in \mathbb{N}$. If $X_k(\omega)\rightarrow 0$ alomost surely, can I say $a_k\rightarrow 0$ in deterministic sense or do I have to say $a_k\rightarrow 0$ almost surely? Is there such a thing as a deterministic sequence converging to a limit almost surely? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

The set $A:={\omega\in\Omega:X_k(\omega)\to0}$ is not empty since $\Bbb P(A)=1$. Choose $\omega\in A$. Then you have a deterministic sequence $X_k(\omega)\to0$  such that $0\le a_k\le X_k(\omega)$ for all $k$. So $a_k\to0$. Although it would look a bit pointless, you can of course see $a_k$ as a random variable where $a_k(\omega)=a_k$ for all $\omega\in\Omega$, in this case you could say that $\Bbb P(a_k\to0)=1$ (i.e., $a_k\to0$ a.s.)

@nejimban Thanks, your comment is in line with Thanh Nguyen's answer. I understand it now. Thank you for your help.

Since $X_k$ converges to $0$ almost surely, that is,
$$\mathbb{P}(\{\omega \in \Omega: X_k(\omega) \rightarrow 0 \text{ as } k \rightarrow \infty\}) = 1
$$
which means, the set $\{\omega \in \Omega: X_k(\omega) \rightarrow 0 \text{ as } k \rightarrow \infty\}$ is not empty (otherwise the probability of an empty set would be $0$). So we can choose some $\omega_0$ such that $X_k(\omega_0) \rightarrow 0$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$.
But, $0 \le a_k \le X_k(\omega_0)$, so by the sandwich theorem, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = 0$ (The limit here is in deterministic sense)

Nguyen , Brilliant!!! Thank you so much.

@ThanhNguyen , Brilliant!!! Thank you so much.
